# Improve tesseract in recognising characters and digits without context

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, detection, yolo

I want to build an application to automatically detect the taxi numbers on taxis in Windhoek to verify if they are registered.
Taxis usually look like this:
[windhoek taxi example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eps5p.jpg)

I trained Yolov8 on detecting the taxi numbers, which works unexpectedly good on a very small dataset. With the predicted bounding box I crop the image to the number and then want to pass it to tesseract. Here is an example of a cropped image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IXW2.jpg)

Now, I'm searching for ways to improve tesseract on this specific data:

The numbers are always in the format (character:digit:digit:digit). Would it help to create a custom dictionary with all the possible codes?

Which pre-processing steps would you suggest?

Is page-segmentation-mode 10 the right choice?

Comment: Which code have you tried, and what is the result?